# How to remove duplicate entries in iTunes

Tags: itunes, duplicate

For some reason, songs in my itunes library are listed twice. Note: It is the exact same song just referenced twice, so removing one of the songs will keep one reference in the library but delete the song efficiently making the remaining song just a dead link.

this is similar to other [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/63818/removing-duplicates-from-itunes-playlist) questions but not exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to use [this project](http://www.scartech.net/2007/10/11/itunes-sdk-and-c-part-2/) to remove the duplicate files. Note the zip file contains the sources as well as binaries, the binaries are in `iTunesCOMSample\iTunesCOMSample\bin\Release\` folder.

Comment: I will try a variation on this, it's the closest answer i s'pose :)

Comment: dang this is gone now...

Answer (score 4):

Open iTunes and click on "View" and "Show Duplicates."

More /additional info:

- [How to remove duplicate entries in iTunes](http://www.ehow.com/how_2135398_remove-duplicate-songs-itunes.html)
- [How to find and remove duplicate items in your iTunes library](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2905)

Comment: bottom 2 links are the same ;)

Comment: @johnt Thanks! Edited. Talking about duplicates ;)

Comment: When you find the duplicates and go to delete one of them, you'll get a choice between "Move to recycle bin" or "Keep file." Make sure you click keep file so the other reference will be unaffected.

Comment: @mvdavid7 if you select keep file, the double entry is kept (nothing happens in iTunes)

Comment: this doesn't work and is not related to my question.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the menu bar, go to File > Library > Organize Library...
2. Check both *Consolidate files* and *Upgrade to iTunes Media organization*. [image]
3. Give your computer some time to process this, depending on how many items you have in your library.
4. It should now be solved. You're done.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: @Makach I'm just curious: what, if anything, happened when you tried this?

Answer (score 2):

Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> key (for Mac OS X), or <kbd>Shift</kbd> (for Windows) -> *View* -> *Show Exact Duplicate Items* to display duplicates as this is normally a more useful selection. You need to manually select all but one of each group to remove. Sorting the list by Date Added may make it easier to select the appropriate tracks, however this works best when performed immediately after the dupes have been created.  If you have multiple entries in iTunes connected to the same file on the hard drive, then don't send to the trash...
http://www.iphone-mac.com/find-delete-duplicate-items-in-itunes-library.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation on KronoS above but I might suggest the following as a **last resort**:

This is assuming that you have previously allowed iTunes to organize your Music such that you have a well formed iTunes music tree (i.e. on a Mac, `~/Music/iTunes/...`).

Go into `~/Music/iTunes` and delete the following files:

- `iTunes Music Library.xml`
- `iTunes Library Genius.itdb`
- `iTunes Library Extras.itdb`
- `iTunes Library`
- Any other very similar `*.db` or `* Music Library *` files in that directory which look to be backups.

At this point you should have got rid of all the extra linking which is causing all your problems.

Once this is complete - you can try the following:

1. Start iTunes as normal.
2. At this point the list of music in iTunes should be blank.
3. Inside iTunes go `File > Add to Library` and select `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/`

This should reimport all your music with only a single entry per file.

**WARNING: This method will kill off all your podcast subscriptions, playlists and possibly album art and should only be used as a last resort.**

Comment: Well of course this will work but I don't want to lose my library...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling itunes?   Also a selection of organize my itunes and then cancelling that operation may cause the duplicates to arise.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the native iTunes duplicate track remover.

You can also follow these instructions in order to remove your duplicate tracks from your iTunes library:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/9226-how-to-remove-duplicate-tracks-in-itunes#add-artwork-and-tags-to-itunes-songs