# Show Duplicate Files

Tags: macos, mac, bash, search, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find duplicate files on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/46690/find-duplicate-files-on-mac-os-x)

Hi all

I am trying to sort out duplicate folders in a folder which again has an awful lot of subfolders on a Mac OS X system. I want to have a list with the absolute paths to the duplicate files. I tried to solve the Problem in the Bash shell but if there is a GUI Application which does this I would prefer it.

Comment: Duplicate files or duplicate folders? And how do you qualify a "duplicate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem a long time ago but didn't have the time to write down the answer. Here it is:

Mac OS X has a tool which can solve the problem in a decent way. It's called FileMerge and can be found in */Developer/Application/Utilities* when you install the Xcode developer tools from the Mac OS X CD.

[image]

It first compares the two folders you selected and then shows the differences. You can then select if you want to merge the files to one destination file.

For further information read this article:

> http://www.macworld.com/article/49584/2006/03/cmpfldr.html

Comment: Would you happen to know if there's a way to get that tool without installing Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

[**Mr.Clean**](http://www.arcobaleno2001.it/) is an excellent free graphical tool for this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's also [CleanMyMac](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac), which is mostly for cleaning and not so much for finding duplicates:

[image]

... and [Chipmunk](http://www.chipmunk-app.com/), which is made to find duplicated files and quickly delete the ones outside or inside the specific folder. Not so good for finding duplicates in the same folder or randomly stored, but you still can be used if you want to go 1 by 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try fdupes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes