# How to find old unused files?

Tags: macos

I want to make room in my OS X hard drive by identifying and removing "dead wood", i.e. files that have not been used in a long time (say, longer than 2 years).

Is there a general tool for identifying old, unused files?

(Note 1: I know of a tool for removing localization files, but I am looking for something far more general than that.  Likewise, I know of tools of to identify large files, but this is not what I am looking for at the moment.)

(Note 2: I'm not interested in a tool thst automatically deletes the old, unused files it finds; I want to be able scan the list of candidate files, and remove any that I want to keep despite their being old and inactive.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using mdfind (Spotlight)

As OS X indexes everything using Spotlight, you have a very powerful command line tool to find what you need:

```
mdfind -onlyin <directory> 'kMDItemLastUsedDate <= $time.today(-<days>)'
```

would for example list everything in `<directory>` that you haven't opened for `<days>`. You can of course leave out the `onlyin` if you want to search system-wide. I'd recommend however to look in specific directories.

You can modify this query with:

- `$time.this_week`
- `$time.this_month`
- `$time.this_year`

and of course also add `$time.this_week(-5)`, for example, if you want something that hasn't been opened for 5 weeks. Or, in your case, using `$time.this_year(-2)` for something that wasn't used in the last two years.

Also, you can access other attributes:

- `kMDItemContentModificationDate` (when it was modified)
- `kMDItemContentCreationDate` (when it was created)

There are a [number of other queries you can make](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html). See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1) for a list of other attributes.

---

#### Using `find`

A simple listing of files in `<directory>` that have been modified more than `<d>` days ago:

```
find <directory> -type f -mtime +<d>
```

So, for example

```
find ~/Documents -type f -mtime +150
```

lists all your files in `~/Documents` that you haven't modified for at least 150 days.

`mtime` is the Unix modification time of a file which is not changed when you (or the system) reads it. Conversely, if you want to list files that have been modified *within* the last 150 days, you would use `-150` instead of `+150`.

Just like `mtime`, there is also `atime`, which designates the last access time. Same syntax:

```
find ~/Documents -type f -atime +150
```

But I'm not too sure it's too precise. At least on OS X, Spotlight seems to be the better option here.

Comment: This is likely going to select hundreds of system-files that are read, not modified.

Comment: No, that's what the `mtime` is for ("modified" time). Reading a file doesn't change its `mtime`.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. It seems that he is asking to delete files that have been 'unused'. Reading a file is still using it. Ergo, mtime does not find 'unused' files.

Comment: @pberlijn Oh, right. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To do this in Finder, select the folder you want to search (e.g. your home directory) and press `Cmd-F`.

Hold down `Option` and click the `...` button (which is a `+` button when you don't press `Option`) to the right of the *predicate editor* (the bar with the search criteria).

Select *none* where it says *any* for the new criteria block, and select either *Last Opened Date* (probably the default) or *Last Modified Date* in the next line. Then, enter your desired time range. It should look somewhat like this:

[image]

You don't need to actually enter a search expression, it'll just list the files that haven't been modified in some time.

Doing this from Finder has the advantage that it's very easy to add additional criteria, and to sort and view the resulting files.

[See this answer on how to add the size column to the Spotlight results list](https://superuser.com/questions/231070/how-to-sort-spotlight-results-by-size-in-the-finder) to selectively delete old *and* large files.

Comment: Oh, +1. I'm so hooked on the Terminal that I forgot it has this UI feature. D'oh.

Comment: @slhck Thanks. It's easy to forget that though ;) —— Could you check that *Last Opened Date* is broken (at least with this method)? I find several more recent files, that were written but never opened again. The *Last Opened* column says *today* though, but it's a result anyway.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not 100% sure but judging from all I've tried the results seem reasonable. At least I'd consider them useful :)

Comment: @slhck So you don't have [this problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eHzG5.png)?

Comment: @Daniel Oh now I see what you mean exactly. Seems as if the attribute is set even if *you* don't open the file. [At least here it's BibDesk.app](http://i.imgur.com/vERxv.png) and a few Adobe folders. All other files seem to be C headers and `/Developer` apps. Strange. March 20 to 25th I set up that machine, installing CS4 and XCode.

Comment: @slhck Well I'm not too concerned about the value in the list, more that they're in the results list. Also, you'd expect them to disappear once you add the *Last Modified* criterium, but they still show up. Remove *Last Opened* (leaving only *Last Modified*) and they disappear. It appears that *Last opened date* is ridiculously useless.

Comment: @Daniel Duh, that's weird. Well, nice to know that at least it *doesn't really work* ;)

Comment: Thanks++ !!!  I wish I could accept both slhck's and your reply, they're both great.  I went with slhck's only because of my fanatical bias in favor of the CLI.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have any objections to me combining our answers and writing a post for the SU blog?

Comment: @slhck Not at all. Go ahead. (if you see a post of mine that seems like good blog material, please let me know -- I'm still struggling with that)

Comment: @Daniel Fine, I'll cc you when I have a draft!

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight.

Enter some wildcard for the type of files you want to delete (or a general wildcard), and add the attribute 'Last opened date'. Set this to your liking.

Be careful what you delete.