# How to identify duplicate files (by name and size) and delete them?

Tags: macos, deduplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find duplicate files on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/46690/find-duplicate-files-on-mac-os-x)

I am trying to grep duplicate files in this selection:

```
find . -name '*.CR2'
```

I want to delete duplicate CR2 on my RAW files archive. How can I grep them maintaining the path? Or is there a better way to remove them?

I'd like to identify them by name and size.

Comment: I doubt this can be done with grep, but there should be other methods. How exactly do you identify duplicate files?

Comment: Add `diff` to your toolbox.

Comment: I want to identify them by name and eventually by size!

Comment: Excuse me guys for my bad english! I can't use "fdupes" because i am using Mac OS! Thanks for support!

Comment: I just found another question dealing with the exact same problem, see: [Find duplicate files on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/46690/find-duplicate-files-on-mac-os-x) — the first answer lists a couple of tools you can try, even if you can't install `fdupes`. (You can install `fdupes` through [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) if you want, but it takes a little to get it set up). If you want to reply to me here, please use `@slhck`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve might be a perfect fit for [fdupes](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fdupes). From the manpage:

> SYNOPSIS
>          fdupes [ options ] DIRECTORY ...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Searches the given path for duplicate files. Such files are found by comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures, followed by a
>   byte-by-byte comparison.